# Multibyte MFC Library doesn't detect Visual Studio

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to build a MFC project with Visual Studio 2013 Express. After googling the MSB8031 error I downloaded the Multibyte MFC Library for Visual Studio 2013. However as I launched the setup it does not detect that Visual Studio is present on my machine. It says something like:

`Microsoft Visual Studio is required but not installed. Install the software and then try it again`

Did someone else encounter this problem? (I installed VS Express 2012 first and then VS Express 2013 after that since the VS2013-setup complained about an unsupported system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MFC isn't included with the Express editions of Visual Studio. You need to use Professional.